# Rationale for the shared_ptr atomic functions taking pointer instead of reference

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, language-lawyer, shared-ptr

As you can see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic), `shared_ptr` is passed as a pointer instead of reference. Also note that

> All these functions invoke undefined behavior if p is a null pointer.

So why pointer? I think in C++, reference should be preferred unless there are specific reasons to use pointer.

Comment: Not sure if this qualifies as an answer but from that page you link to: *These functions are typically implemented using mutexes, stored in a global hash table where the pointer value is used as the key.*.  So maybe the implementation defined the interface.

Comment: Maybe it makes clearer that it does not increment the reference count locally from the side of the caller. That's the only reason I can think of.

Comment: @NathanOliver  In my opinion, this is an implementation detail which should be hidden from the user.

Comment: In C11 [<stdatomic.h>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic#Functions) contains a set of functions with exactly the same names, taking a pointer as parameter. Wouldn't it be strange if C++ defined a different interface for those functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template< class T >
bool atomic_is_lock_free( const std::shared_ptr<T>* p );
```

takes a pointer to a smart pointer because this is a special case of the more generic [`atomic_is_lock_free`](http://fr.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_is_lock_free):

```
template< class Atomic >
bool atomic_is_lock_free(const Atomic* obj)
```

where `Atomic` is `std::shared_ptr<T>`. The same goes for all template function [`atomic_*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic).

As user luk32 noticed, this only answer the question partially: *"While [...] such signature is demanded by template interface, it immediately begs to reapply the question and ask why the generic interface wasn't designed to use reference."*

Well, those [`<atomic>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_is_lock_free) signatures come originally from the GCC C extensions [citation needed] functions [`__sync_*`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html). Since `C` does not have references, the C++ committee might [citation needed] had the will to mimic those functions and provide an easy way to update code relying on those builtins.

Comment: I don't think that really answers the question. While it's true, that such signature is demanded by template interface, it immediately begs to reapply the question and ask why the generic interface wasn't designed to use reference.

Comment: Your linked example is wrong. It's because your `using` declaration is inside the function `main`, which hides the `atomic_is_lock_free` outside. Move your `using` to outside, compile fine.

Comment: @liliscent That's true, and it would also be true if the Standard Library defined a reference-taking `atomic_is_lock_free` inside `std::`. Fixed.

Comment: This is not a partial specialization.